# Json schema check keys presence if another key equals some value (draft 4)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to validate a json key presence, only if another key exists AND equals some value.

For instance, on the following json I want the presence of "baz" only if "key" equals "foo":

```
{
    "id":"myid",
    "key":"foo",
    "baz":"baz!"
}
```

I can validate it simply using following json schema (draft 4):

```
{
    "properties": 
    {
        "key":{
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["foo", "bar"]
        },
        "baz":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "quuz":{
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "anyOf":
    [
        {
            "properties":{
                "key":{ "enum": ["foo"] }
            },
            "required": ["baz"]
        },
        {
            "properties":{
                "key":{ "enum": ["bar"] }
            },
            "required": ["quuz"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The following json is valid as well:

```
{
    "id":"myid",
    "key":"bar",
    "quuz":"quuz!"
}
```

This is not valid ("key" = "bar" requires "quuz"):

```
{
    "id":"myid",
    "key":"bar",
    "baz":"baz!"
}
```

So far, so good. Now: I need the json being valid also if the "key" key is missing:

```
{
    "id":"myid"
}
```

This just does not work with the above schema, because the "anyOf" keyword sets the "required" fields.

Is it possible to get a "anyOf or missing key" behavior?. Draf

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement that logic by describing two exclusive subschemas, with and without `key`:

```
{
  "properties":
  {
    "key":{
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["foo", "bar"]
    },
    "baz":{
      "type": "string"
    },
    "quuz":{
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "oneOf":
  [
    {
      "not": {"required": ["key"]}
    },
    {
      "required": ["key"],
      "anyOf": [
      {
        "properties":{
          "key":{ "enum": ["foo"] }
        },
        "required": ["baz"]
      },
      {
        "properties":{
          "key":{ "enum": ["bar"] }
        },
        "required": ["quuz"]
      }
    ]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Never underestimate the power of `not`

Comment: actually it will work, because it will trigger 2 subschemas of `oneOf`: 0 and 2, you can quick check at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: almost there, it validates an empty json. 
But assuming the   json:

    {
        "baz":"BAAAZZ"
    }

validates one of the (oneOf) conditions. 

Here two of the oneOf conditions are triggered:

    {
        "baz":"",
        "quuz":""
    }

even though "key" is missing. 
I'd need the oneOf conditions triggered only if "key":"foo" or "bar", to be ignored instead.